# How to conditionalize Concourse git-resource trigger based on paths when there is a shared component directory?

Tags: git, concourse

My git repo has 3 top-level directories:

`-\
  |- ComponentA
  |- ComponentB
  |- SharedLib`

I can use separate git-resources with different paths to trigger the builds for component A, component B and the shared library. But the SharedLib is a build dependency for ComponentA and ComponentB and sometimes commits include files in both ComponentA and SharedLib.

What I want is to be sure that commits that span ComponentA and the sharedlib (and perhaps also ComponentB) first build SharedLib and then the components.

What is the best way to structure the pipeline in Concourse to do this?
(I know that I could pull the shareLib into a separate repo, but there are reasons this would be awkward.)

I thought about extending the git-resource to have a "unless_path" property. But thinking through how the pipeline would handle the different possible commit sequences with commits overlapping pipeline runs made my head hurt.

Comment: Why do you want to use paths in this case?

I think we can come up with a pipeline that doesn't use paths.

Comment: That would be fine. I'ld prefer not messing with/change the standard git-resource (where I could implement the behavior also). I can't easily see how to get a setup where componentA and sharedLib are "triggered" but ignore the trigger in the case of a simultaneous commit to both. I guess I could check the change set in the initial task and conditionally run code in the task, but then I don't get a nice high level representation of the logical blocks.

Comment: But is there a specific reason you want separate jobs and separate resources?

Comment: Not necessarily. What would be your recommendation? One of the things I'm not understanding about concourse resources in general is whether doing an untriggered -get (in script) changes the ref for subsequent triggering purposes. I guess I could just do an experiment to figure that out.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me like your general desire is to take this mono-repo and use it to build three modules, with `SharedLib` being built before `ComponentA` and/or `ComponentB`.

In that case I'd model it something like this:

```
resources:
- name: repo
  type: git
  source:
    uri: ...

jobs:
- name: build
  plan:
  - get: repo
    trigger: true
  - task: build-shared-lib
    file: repo/ci/build-shared-lib.yml
  - aggregate:
    - task: build-component-a
      file: repo/ci/build-component-a.yml
    - task: build-component-b
      file: repo/ci/build-component-b.yml
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm guessing this builds the library on all commits. The underlying problem is what you are pointing out. Using a mono-repo to build three components.